# How do I make child and parent entities in GAE Python?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, python-2.7

I have the following database models in my application:

```
class Account(ndb.Model):
    username = ndb.StringProperty()
    userid = ndb.IntegerProperty()
    email = ndb.StringProperty()

class Post(nbd.Model):
    text = nbd.StringProperty()
```

How can I tell the program that "many posts belong to one account" ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple ways I think.  One easy way is to just add another field on the Post model which ties it to the Account.  e.g. assuming that all accounts have a unique `userid`:

```
def Post(ndb.Model):
    text = ndb.StringProperty()
    userid = ndb.IntegerProperty()
```

Now, if you have an account, you can get it's "children" by querying where the userid is the same as that of the account.

A second way is to structure your data for "strong consistency" by using ["ancestor paths"](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/entities#Python_Ancestor_paths).  Then you can get the posts by doing an ["ancestor query"](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/queries#Python_Ancestor_filters).